# how to convert 270921sec into days + hours + minutes + sec ? (ruby)

Tags: ruby, time

I have a number of seconds. Let's say 270921. How can I display that number saying it is xx days, yy hours, zz minutes, ww seconds?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

It can be done pretty concisely using `divmod`:

```
t = 270921
mm, ss = t.divmod(60)            #=> [4515, 21]
hh, mm = mm.divmod(60)           #=> [75, 15]
dd, hh = hh.divmod(24)           #=> [3, 3]
puts "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds" % [dd, hh, mm, ss]
#=> 3 days, 3 hours, 15 minutes and 21 seconds
```

You could probably DRY it further by getting creative with `collect`, or maybe `inject`, but when the core logic is three lines it may be overkill.

Comment: @Mike Woodhouse: that is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: +1, What if I need to show the seconds till 90 mins for example Im tracking a game. it should show something like 90:54. Thanks!

Comment: @uDaY see my enhanced answer. I don't quite understand what you're trying to do, but maybe it will help.

Comment: Thanks for this, I got to create a neat little method for it:
def seconds_to_dhms(seconds);
  [60,60,24].map{ |dm| seconds,t = seconds.divmod(dm); t }.reverse.unshift seconds;
end

Comment: Is is better to use this code or Benchmark class to do benchmarking (i.e just calculate the time take to do some job)?

Comment: How do you do AM or PM?

Comment: Not sure if this is happening for anyone else, but my seconds came out as `49.73596399999224` so I rounded the seconds like this: `ss.to_f.round(0)`

Answer (score 13):

I was hoping there would be an easier way than using divmod, but this is the most DRY and reusable way I found to do it:

```
def seconds_to_units(seconds)
  '%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds' %
    # the .reverse lets us put the larger units first for readability
    [24,60,60].reverse.inject([seconds]) {|result, unitsize|
      result[0,0] = result.shift.divmod(unitsize)
      result
    }
end
```

The method is easily adjusted by changing the format string and the first inline array (ie the [24,60,60]).

**Enhanced version**

```
class TieredUnitFormatter
  # if you set this, '%d' must appear as many times as there are units
  attr_accessor :format_string

  def initialize(unit_names=%w(days hours minutes seconds), conversion_factors=[24, 60, 60])
    @unit_names = unit_names
    @factors = conversion_factors

    @format_string = unit_names.map {|name| "%d #{name}" }.join(', ')
    # the .reverse helps us iterate more effectively
    @reversed_factors = @factors.reverse
  end

  # e.g. seconds
  def format(smallest_unit_amount)
    parts = split(smallest_unit_amount)
    @format_string % parts
  end

  def split(smallest_unit_amount)
    # go from smallest to largest unit
    @reversed_factors.inject([smallest_unit_amount]) {|result, unitsize|
      # Remove the most significant item (left side), convert it, then
      # add the 2-element array to the left side of the result.
      result[0,0] = result.shift.divmod(unitsize)
      result
    }
  end
end
```

Examples:

```
fmt = TieredUnitFormatter.new
fmt.format(270921)  # => "3 days, 3 hours, 15 minutes, 21 seconds"

fmt = TieredUnitFormatter.new(%w(minutes seconds), [60])
fmt.format(5454)  # => "90 minutes, 54 seconds"
fmt.format_string = '%d:%d'
fmt.format(5454)  # => "90:54"
```

Note that `format_string` won't let you change the order of the parts (it's always the most significant value to least). For finer grained control, you can use `split` and manipulate the values yourself.

Answer (score 12):

Rails has an helper which converts distance of time in words.
You can look its implementation: [distance_of_time_in_words](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb)

Comment: Is there a way to use it outside of Rails?

Comment: Yes.  include  ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper !

Comment: a  = distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 50.minutes)  
 => "about 1 hour" 
1.9.2-p290 :035 >

Comment: Thank you! Very useful! <%= distance_of_time_in_words(message.created_at, Time.now, options = {}) %>

Answer (score 11):

Needed a break. Golfed this up:

```
s = 270921
dhms = [60,60,24].reduce([s]) { |m,o| m.unshift(m.shift.divmod(o)).flatten }
# => [3, 3, 15, 21]
```

Comment: You just copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51279357/865175).

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Rails, there is an easy way if you don't need the precision:

```
time_ago_in_words 270921.seconds.from_now
# => 3 days
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the simplest method I found for this problem:

```
  def formatted_duration total_seconds
    hours = total_seconds / (60 * 60)
    minutes = (total_seconds / 60) % 60
    seconds = total_seconds % 60
    "#{ hours } h #{ minutes } m #{ seconds } s"
  end
```

You can always adjust returned value to your needs.

```
2.2.2 :062 > formatted_duration 3661
 => "1 h 1 m 1 s"
```

Answer (score 3):

I modified the answer given by @Mike to add dynamic formatting based on the size of the result

```
      def formatted_duration(total_seconds)
        dhms = [60, 60, 24].reduce([total_seconds]) { |m,o| m.unshift(m.shift.divmod(o)).flatten }

        return "%d days %d hours %d minutes %d seconds" % dhms unless dhms[0].zero?
        return "%d hours %d minutes %d seconds" % dhms[1..3] unless dhms[1].zero?
        return "%d minutes %d seconds" % dhms[2..3] unless dhms[2].zero?
        "%d seconds" % dhms[3]
      end
```

Answer (score 2):

I just start writing ruby. i guess this is only for 1.9.3

```
def dateBeautify(t)

    cute_date=Array.new
    tables=[ ["day", 24*60*60], ["hour", 60*60], ["minute", 60], ["sec", 1] ]

    tables.each do |unit, value|
        o = t.divmod(value)
        p_unit = o[0] > 1 ? unit.pluralize : unit
        cute_date.push("#{o[0]} #{unit}") unless o[0] == 0
        t = o[1]
    end
    return cute_date.join(', ')

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Number of days = 270921/86400 (Number of seconds in day) = 3 days this is the absolute number

seconds remaining (t) = 270921 - 3*86400 = 11721

```
3.to_s + Time.at(t).utc.strftime(":%H:%M:%S")
```

Which will produce something like 3:03:15:21

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to the OP but it might help someone who lands here.

I had this string

```
"Sorry, you cannot change team leader in the last #{freeze_period_time} of a #{competition.kind}"
```

`freeze_period_time` resolved to 5 days inside `irb`, but inside the string, it resolved to time in seconds eg `47200`, so the string became something ugly

```
"Sorry, you cannot change team leader in the last 47200 of a hackathon"
```

To fix it, I had to use `.inspect` on the `freeze_period_time` object.

So the following made it work

```
"Sorry, you cannot change team leader in the last #{freeze_period_time.inspect} of a #{competition.kind}"
```

Which returned the correct sentence

```
"Sorry, you cannot change team leader in the last 5 days of a hackathon"
```

TLDR

You might need `time.inspect` - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ruby-time-inspect-function/