# Ruby: Convert time to seconds?

Tags: ruby, time

How can I convert a time like 10:30 to seconds? Is there some sort of built in Ruby function to handle that?

Basically trying to figure out the number of seconds from midnight (00:00) to a specific time in the day (such as 10:30, or 18:45).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime#parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/DateTime.html#M002797) to turn a string into a `DateTime` object, and then multiply the hour by 3600 and the minute by 60 to get the number of seconds:

```
require 'date'

# DateTime.parse throws ArgumentError if it can't parse the string
if dt = DateTime.parse("10:30") rescue false 
  seconds = dt.hour * 3600 + dt.min * 60 #=> 37800
end
```

As [Josh Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19750/josh-lee) pointed out in the comments, you could also use [`Time#seconds_since_midnight`](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Time/Calculations.html#M000851) if you have ActiveSupport:

```
require 'active_support'
Time.parse("10:30").seconds_since_midnight #=> 37800.0
```

Comment: This seems to require Active Support.

Comment: Also, there’s a `seconds_since_midnight` method.

Comment: In regards to the ArgumentError...is there a way to convert a number to time? So say the input was just "8"...I'd want to convert to "8:00"

Comment: @jleedev Updated to use `DateTime#parse` instead.

Comment: In order to reverse this take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310197/how-to-convert-270921sec-into-days-hours-minutes-sec-ruby

Answer (score 14):

Yet another implementation:

```
Time.now.to_i - Date.today.to_time.to_i # seconds since midnight
```

Answer (score 9):

The built in [time](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/time/rdoc/index.html) library extends the Time class to parse strings, so you could use that. They're ultimately represented as seconds since the UNIX epoch, so converting to integers and subtracting should get you what you want.

```
require 'time'
m = Time.parse('00:00')
t = Time.parse('10:30')

(t.to_i - m.to_i)
=> 37800
```

There's also some sugar in ActiveSupport to handle these types of things.

Comment: Note. when applied on a DateTime object, this will return a string with current date, which may or may not confuse matters if doing calculations overlapping midnight.

Comment: Is there a way to parse 10:30 as 10 minutes and 30 seconds?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps there is a more succinct way, but:

```
t = Time.parse("18:35")
s = t.hour * 60 * 60 + t.min * 60 + t.sec
```

would do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use

```
Time.parse("10:30").seconds_since_midnight
```

Comment: `seconds_since_midnight` is not a method in Ruby, maybe it's in Rails?

Answer (score 2):

I like these answers very much, especially [Teddy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16742119/5958455) for its tidyness.

There's one thing to note. Teddy's answer gives second of day **in current region** and I haven't been able to convert `Date.today.to_time` to UTC. I ended up with this workaround:

```
Time.now.to_i % 86400
```

It's based on the fact that `Time.now.to_i` gives **seconds since Unix Epoch** which is always `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`, regardless of your current time zone. And the fact that there's 86400 seconds in a day as well. So this solution will always give you seconds since last **UTC** midnight.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'time'

def seconds_since_midnight(time)
  Time.parse(time).hour * 3600 + Time.parse(time).min * 60 + Time.parse(time).sec
end

puts seconds_since_midnight("18:46")
```

All great answers, this is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

In plain ruby the fastest is the sum of time parts:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'time'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('date') { 100_000.times { Time.now.to_i - Date.today.to_time.to_i } }
  x.report('parse') { 100_000.times { Time.now.to_i - Time.parse('00:00').to_i } }
  x.report('sum') { 100_000.times { Time.now.hour * 3600 + Time.now.min * 60 + Time.now.sec } }
end

       user     system      total        real
date  0.820000   0.000000   0.820000 (  0.822578)
parse  1.510000   0.000000   1.510000 (  1.516117)
sum  0.270000   0.000000   0.270000 (  0.268540)
```

So, here is a method that takes timezone into account, if needed

```
def seconds_since_midnight(time: Time.now, utc: true)
  time = time.utc if utc
  time.hour * 3600 + time.min * 60 + time.sec
end
```