# Subtract two dates and return it in seconds in the query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

hi everyone im new to rails, I am trying to make a query using 3 parameters

```
 def zones_by_container
    container_id= params[:container_id]
    start_time = params[:start_time_at]
    end_time = params[:end_time_at]
    container =Container.find(container_id)

    @Zone = Zone.where(customer: container.customer_id,container: container_id, 
    start_time_at: start_time..end_time).select('address, start_time_at, end_time_at, 
    notified_at, end_time_at - start_time_at as `Time`').as_json(:except => :id)
 
    render json: { status: 'Success',data: @zone}

end
```

I would like the subtraction of the dates to return it in seconds in my query
This is an example of my query with the two parameters

```
 {
        "start_time_at": "2022-11-24 10:10:16",
        "end_time_at": "2022-11-24 10:11:20",
        "Time": 104
    },
```

I want the result to look like this

```
 {
        "start_time_at": "2022-11-24 10:10:16",
        "end_time_at": "2022-11-24 10:11:20",
        "Time": 64
    },
```

Could someone help me so that the subtraction of the two dates comes out in seconds, I have searched and I did not find how to solve this problem

Comment: What database are you using? A somewhat polyglot solution would be `EXTRACT('epoch' FROM end_time_at ) - EXTRACT('epoch' FROM start_time_at) AS Time`. The alias should really be `snake_case` though.

Comment: database mysql , 
It hasn't worked for me

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby: Convert time to seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824369/ruby-convert-time-to-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
select('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time_at) as time')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on rails is really flexible about managing Dates and time. This is something that i am sure will do the work(you just have to put the dates of your choice):

```
now = Time.now => 2022-12-02 11:31:50.677627 +0200 
tomorrow = Time.now + 24.hours => 2022-12-03 11:32:05.119234 +0200 
result_in_seconds = tomorrow - now =>  86414.441607
```

86414.441607 > 86400 because i used my console.If you run this code in your program you will get a more accurate result.Hope that helps.Let me know if you need anything.

Answer (score -1):

What about to do it in JSON file?

```
(start_date_time - end_date_time).to_f
```

Comment: yes, the time in seconds should appear in the json file