# how can I convert milliseconds in String format to HH:MM:SS format in Ruby in under 3 lines of code?

Tags: ruby

```
@scores_raw.each do |score_raw|
  # below is code if time was being sent in milliseconds
  hh = ((score_raw.score.to_i)/100)/3600
  mm = (hh-hh.to_i)*60
  ss = (mm-mm.to_i)*60
  crumbs = [hh,mm,ss]
  sum = crumbs.first.to_i*3600+crumbs[1].to_i*60+crumbs.last.to_i
  @scores << {:secs => sum, :hms => hh.round.to_s+":"+mm.round.to_s+":"+ss.round.to_s}
  @scores_hash << {:secs => sum, :hms => hh.round.to_s+":"+mm.round.to_s+":"+ss.round.to_s}
  # milliseconds case end
end
```

That's my current code but I hate it. It's looks messy. It doesn't just look great at all. Maybe someone whose an expert in ruby could tell how to do this by chaining collects, reduces etc and making it look good?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Time class ruby provides provides `at` function to get time from seconds. Use this it will cure.

```
miliseconds = 32290928
seconds = miliseconds/1000


Time.at(seconds).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

OR to get utc time

```
#Get UTC Time
Time.at(seconds).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the shortest amount of LOC.

Comment: @qwexar Problem with `at` is you need to give miliseconds counting from `1970`. `Time.at(0) #=> Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 +0530 1970`. And `at` function won't give `mili-seconds` equivalent `HH:MM:SS`. It hives results relative to `Time.at(0)`

Comment: @Taimoor Changaiz its not correct it gives time relative to `Time.at(0)`.

Comment: @checkit So whats the hack to get current time with at method, I think we could manipulate given miliseconds with relative?

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap this in a helper method:

```
def format_milisecs(m)
  secs, milisecs = m.divmod(1000) # divmod returns [quotient, modulus]
  mins, secs = secs.divmod(60)
  hours, mins = mins.divmod(60)

  [secs,mins,hours].map { |e| e.to_s.rjust(2,'0') }.join ':'
end

format_milisecs 10_600_00
=> "03:13:20"
```

Comment: have you mixed up the order in the array? I would've expected `[hours,mins,secs]`.

Answer (score 3):

Nice solution given by @Mike Woodhouse :

Use `divmod` :

```
t = 270921000
ss, ms = t.divmod(1000)          #=> [270921, 0]
mm, ss = ss.divmod(60)           #=> [4515, 21] 
hh, mm = mm.divmod(60)           #=> [75, 15]
dd, hh = hh.divmod(24)           #=> [3, 3]
puts "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds" % [dd, hh, mm, ss]
#=> 3 days, 3 hours, 15 minutes and 21 seconds
```

Answer is  [how to convert 270921sec into days + hours + minutes + sec ? (ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310197/how-to-convert-270921sec-into-days-hours-minutes-sec-ruby)