# Rails 3 get days between two MySQL dates

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, date, datetime, date-format

I want to be able to work out the number of days between two dates. One date is the current date, the other is from a database of events.

So far, I have tried this in my Model:

```
    this_date = DateTime.parse(self.date.to_s)
    the_date = Time.now
    between = (this_date.to_i - the_date.to_i)
```

Which was a suggestion from another question (well, kinda).

The date format from the database is 'YYYY/mm/dd', and the date from `Time.now` is a lot different which is what I cannot work out.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: use `Date.today` instead of `Time.now`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this_date = Date.parse self.date
remaing_days = (Date.today - this_date)
```

Comment: There is no need to parse a date column to a string and then back to a date, and less need to store it in a variable - that's unnecessary memory overhead.

Answer (score 1):

What data type is the db column for `self.date` in your model? I note you're casting it to a string so what was it originally? If it's a datetime type then you can skip the `DateTime.parse` and just compare the two dates directly to get the difference in seconds:

```
difference = self.date - Time.now
```

The fun part is then converting that difference to usable values. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310197/how-to-convert-270921sec-into-days-hours-minutes-sec-ruby) has an excellent answer to that.

Edit: for a Date column you can do:

```
difference = (self.date - Date.today).to_i
```

Which will give you a difference in whole days.

Comment: Rails will convert the data to a date object for you if the column is a proper datetime type, no need for any conversion on your part.

Comment: @StefanDunn - have added example for Date column as well.

Comment: Thanks, that what I needed. Same solution as @Strik3r

Comment: @StefanDunn Not exactly, you really don't need to parse a date column to a string, then back into a date! And you don't need to store it in an extra variable.

Answer (score 0):

select (unix_timestamp(first_date)-unix_timestamp(second_date))/84600 from table

84600 is seconds in one day
unix_timestamp is date as seconds since 1970-01-01

So you don't need Ruby :-)

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is answered, but I am posting my solution to this problem, that helped me to solve my problem. I have used:

```
Time.zone.now  > e.start && Time.zone.now  < e.end +  1.day
```