# Dividing seconds into hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a Rails 3 app and I need to display a given time (got the time in seconds) in this exact format:

```
0 hours, 3 minutes and 39 seconds
```

Right now I display it as 00:03:39.

How can I do this?

Thankful for all help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert 270921sec into days + hours + minutes + sec ? (ruby)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310197/how-to-convert-270921sec-into-days-hours-minutes-sec-ruby)

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595840/rails-get-the-time-difference-in-hours-minutes-and-seconds/19596579#19596579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
seconds = 219

hours = seconds / 3600
seconds -= hours * 3600

minutes = seconds / 60
seconds -= minutes * 60

puts "#{hours} hours, #{minutes} minutes and #{seconds} seconds"
```