# Rails - Get the time difference in hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for an idiomatic way to get the time passed since a given date in hours, minutes and seconds.

If the given date is 2013-10-25 23:55:00 and the current date is 2013-10-27 20:55:09, the returning value should be 45:03:09. The [time_difference](https://github.com/tmlee/time_difference) and [time_diff](https://github.com/abhidsm/time_diff) gems won't work with this requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert 270921sec into days + hours + minutes + sec ? (ruby)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310197/how-to-convert-270921sec-into-days-hours-minutes-sec-ruby)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
def time_diff(start_time, end_time)
  seconds_diff = (start_time - end_time).to_i.abs

  hours = seconds_diff / 3600
  seconds_diff -= hours * 3600

  minutes = seconds_diff / 60
  seconds_diff -= minutes * 60

  seconds = seconds_diff

  "#{hours.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}:#{minutes.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}:#{seconds.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}"
  # or, as hagello suggested in the comments:
  # '%02d:%02d:%02d' % [hours, minutes, seconds]
end
```

And use it:

```
time_diff(Time.now, Time.now-2.days-3.hours-4.minutes-5.seconds)
# => "51:04:04"
```

Comment: Is is better to use this code or Benchmark class to do benchmarking (i.e just calculate the time take to do some job)?

Comment: You should use built-in Benchmarks or a gem for that. "don't reinvent the wheel" ;-)

Comment: Doesn't that "to_i" render the resulting rational from the subtraction as rounded off quite a lot? Whenever I use it, I end up getting '0' even for things that have taken several minutes. IT seems like you would need to use `to_f`, right?

Comment: What about replacing `"#{hours.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}:#{minutes.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}:#{seconds.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}"` with `'%02d:%02d:%02d' % [hours, minutes, seconds]`?

Comment: @hagello because I did not think about it! Thank you for the suggestion, I will add it to the answer and give you the credits for it

Answer (score 36):

```
time_diff = Time.now - 2.minutes.ago
Time.at(time_diff.to_i.abs).utc.strftime "%H:%M:%S"
=> "00:01:59"
```

Or if your app is picky about rounding, just replace to_i to round:

```
  Time.at(time_diff.round.abs).utc.strftime "%H:%M:%S"
   => => "00:02:00"
```

Not sure about the idiomatic part though

Update: If time difference is expected to be more than 24 hours then the above code is not correct. If such is the case, one could follow the answer of @MrYoshiji or adjust above solution to calculate hours from a datetime object manually:

```
def test_time time_diff
  time_diff = time_diff.round.abs
  hours = time_diff / 3600

  dt = DateTime.strptime(time_diff.to_s, '%s').utc
  "#{hours}:#{dt.strftime "%M:%S"}"
end

test_time Time.now - 28.hours.ago - 2.minutes - 12.seconds
=> "27:57:48" 
test_time Time.now - 8.hours.ago - 2.minutes - 12.seconds
=> "7:57:48" 
test_time Time.now - 24.hours.ago - 2.minutes - 12.seconds
=> "23:57:48" 
test_time Time.now - 25.hours.ago - 2.minutes - 12.seconds
=> "24:57:48"
```

Comment: does not work with `time_diff = Time.now - 2.days.ago`, returns 23:59:59

Comment: Well 1 second is lost due to the rounding. You could change to_i call to round if it is relevant to your application logic

Comment: This is very clean but it never returns anything past 24 hours.

Comment: darnit! Updated the answer :/

Comment: @MrYoshiji - Is his answer correct now? Are there any test cases one can make to validate his latest code?

Comment: Test cases are embedded in the answer

Answer (score 8):

There's a method for that:

`Time.now.minus_with_coercion(10.seconds.ago)`

equals 10 (in fact, 9.99..., use `.round` if you want a 10).

Source: http://apidock.com/rails/Time/minus_with_coercion

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 3):

Since this has not been marked as duplicate, and [the response in the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2311415/6320039) is just way clearer IMHO. I'll add it here for more visibility:

> It can be done pretty concisely using `divmod`:
>
> ```
> t = (end_time - start_time).round.abs
> mm, ss = t.divmod(60)
> hh, mm = mm.divmod(60)
> puts "%02d:%02d:%02d" % [hh, mm, ss]
> ```
>
> You could probably DRY it further by getting creative with `collect`, or maybe `inject`, but when the core logic is three lines it may be overkill.

Note that I've changed a bit the answer to fit better this thread's question.

Answer (score -1):

Once you get the time difference in seconds, you could do something like this

```
Time.at(t).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Where `t` is the time difference in seconds

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work if your diff is greater than one day...