# Rails - Time arithmetic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

I was playing time arithmetic in rails console. I have subtracted two different times and got back a long number, please see below my code.

```
a = User.find(1).updated_at   # returns   Mon, 03 Mar 2014 11:07:43 UTC +00:00
b = User.find(1).created_at   # returns   Mon, 03 Mar 2014 08:36:50 UTC +00:00 

a - b                         # returns   9053.699814796448
```

My question is. What is this number `9053.699814796448`? Is it time? What is it's unit? and how is that calculated? Is it possible to change the default unit of the outcome?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a - b` gives you the time in ***seconds***. Check out the [`Time#-`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-2D) .

Comment: Thanks for the comment, is it possoble to change the time in **hours**?  instead of `9053.699814796448` seconds

Comment: @laman I'm sure you know how many seconds go into an hour, so you can just convert the seconds to hours by dividing by that number :-)

Comment: @laman Do some basic arithmetic like seconds to hours conversions.

Comment: @Daniël Knippers haha lol, so I can't do something like `c =  9053.699814796448 ` and `c.hour`

Comment: @laman This is for you [Rails - Get the time difference in hours, minutes and seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595840/rails-get-the-time-difference-in-hours-minutes-and-seconds) :-)