# How to dry `DD:HH:MM:SS` time format logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time

I want to get:

- `60s` format when `sec==60` (`dd==0 && hh==0 && mm==0`)
- `1min 30s` format when `sec==90`  (`dd==0 && hh==0`)
- etc.

I did this:

```
def sec_int2str(sec)
  mm, ss = sec.divmod(60)
  hh, mm = mm.divmod(60)
  dd, hh = hh.divmod(24)
  if dd==0 && hh==0 && mm==0
    "#{ss}s"
  elsif dd==0 && hh==0
    "#{mm}min #{ss}s"
  elsif dd==0
    "#{hh}h #{mm}min #{ss}s"
  else
    "#{dd}d #{hh}h #{mm}min #{ss}s"
  end
end
```

but the logic is too complex. How can I simply convert?

Comment: What are `ssS`, `mmM`?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't python?

Comment: @AndyGauge this is another way to format strings in ruby, just try this

Comment: @sawa output like `60s` `1min 30s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already identified, you're basically doing the same operation (`Numeric#divmod`) over and over again, but with different intervals (60, 60, 24). A straightforward solution to me, then, is to put those intervals in a data structure along with the corresponding labels:

```
UNITS = {
  "s"   => 60,
  "min" => 60,
  "h"   => 24,
  "d"   => Float::INFINITY
}.freeze
```

Note the use of `Float::INFINITY` for our "top" interval. Now we can use `Enumerable#reduce` to iterate over the intervals and labels, in each iteration dividing the previous `divmod` quotient by the new interval:

```
def sec_int2str(quo)
  UNITS.reduce([]) do |memo, (unit, int)|
    break memo if quo == 0
    break memo.unshift("#{quo}#{unit}") if quo == int
    quo, rem = quo.divmod(int)
    memo.unshift("#{rem.to_i}#{unit}")
  end.join(' ')
end
```

As you can see, the first `break` ends the iteration early if the quotient is 0 so we don't get `0d 0h ...`. The second `break` ends the iteration if the quotient is equal to the current interval so we get `60s` instead of `1h 0s` (and `24h ...` instead of `1d 0h ...`).

Let's test it out:

```
secs = 1
mins = 60 * secs
hrs  = 60 * mins
days = 24 * hrs

[ 60 * secs,
  90 * secs,
  60 * mins,
  90 * mins + 15 * secs,
   6 * hrs  + 55 * mins + 30 * secs,
   1 * days + 10 * secs,
  75 * hrs  + 30 * mins
].each do |num|
  printf("%6d => %s\n", num, sec_int2str(num))
end
```

Output:

```
    60 => 60s
    90 => 1min 30s
  3600 => 60min 0s
  5415 => 1h 30min 15s
 24930 => 6h 55min 30s
 86410 => 24h 0min 10s
271800 => 3d 3h 30min 0s
```

Looks good!

Comment: That's magic work! So seems to learn mathematics is a very important.

Comment: The only math here that's not in your own code is `Float::INFINITY`, which is just a trick to get `n` out of `n.divmod(x)` (because when you integer-divide by infinity the remainder is always the numerator). Alternatively we could have used `nil` and then done an explicit `int.nil?` check in every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [how to convert 270921sec into days + hours + minutes + sec ? (ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310197/how-to-convert-270921sec-into-days-hours-minutes-sec-ruby) you take the incoming seconds and get `hh` `mm` and `ss`.

Then you can:

```
[
  hh>0 && "#{hh} hours",
  mm>0 && "#{mm} minutes",
  ss>0 && "#{ss} seconds",
].join ', '
```

Of course you could get "2 hours, 4 seconds" out of this if the minutes are zero.