# Ruby On Rails - Working out hour/days countdown by subtracting a DateTime column and DateTime now

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I'm basically trying to get a countdown of the hours (and if more than 24 hours, then `x` days) before a set `DateTime` value column in a table using `DateTime.now` but all my attempts result in an error, I know I must be doing something like trying to subtract a float and a string or something...

I've got a `question` table and a `fixture_date` column which is a `datetime` type column, what I've tried so far:

- `question.fixture_date - DateTime.now`
- Error: `undefined method '-' for nil:NilClass`
- `question.fixture_date - Date.today`
- Error: `undefined method '-@' for Tue, 26 Apr 2016:Date Did you mean?  -`
- `question.fixture_date - Time.now`
- Error: `undefined method '-' for nil:NilClass`

They all return errors, what is the correct syntax? Perhaps it's something to do with the `datetime` column, should I be using an alternative?

Comment: What is the error message? Btw what is the result of `question.fixture_date.class` ?

Comment: I updated with error messages :-) If I reverse them, the first two return `expected numeric` and the last one returns `can't convert nil into an exact number`

Comment: yeah this is the problem with your `fixture_date of question`, just make sure it not nil

Comment: Ahh, I do have one in the database that is `NILL`. I will update them all and report back.

Comment: I just answered with the detail why you got different messages, check and give me any feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

the because `question.fixture_date` isn't a date, in your cases is `nil` or `String`, so use `::parse` method of `Time` of ruby stdlib, to get valid time from string, and catch the exception when `nil`:

```
require 'time'

begin
  Time.parse(question.fixture_date) - Time.zone.now
rescue TypeError
  nil
end
```

Comment: Ahh this is cool :-) But how do I write this to the HTML? Unless I'm doing something wrong it's not writing to the page.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, your error came from a `question` which has `fixture_date = nil`.

Explain the error message:

1. **question.fixture_date - DateTime.now**

   ```
   undefined method '-' for nil:NilClass
   ```

   Because `question.fixture_date` returns nil and method `-` doesn't exist for NilClass. To verify this, let run:

   ```
   nil.methods.include?(:-)
   # => false
   ```
2. **DateTime.now - question.fixture_date**

   ```
   TypeError: can't convert nil into an exact number
   ```

   Because method `-` do exist for DateTime.now, but the parameter nil is not valid. To verify this, let run

   ```
   Time.now.methods.include?(:-)
   # =>  true
   ```

In summary, the root cause is just your `fixture_date = nil`, try to fix that with a simple code, eg:

```
<% if question.fixture_date %>
   <% delta = question.fixture_date - DateTime.now %>
   <!-- Your code here to use delta -->
<% end %>
```

Otherwise, if you want to make sure `fixture_date` is not nil always, make a rails validation for it in your `Question` model

Comment: Ah this is great, thanks for the info :-) Is there an easy way to get a countdown style thing working? Like "2 Days 3 Hours Left" based on subtracting the `datetime` fixture_date and `DateTime.now` code? Would I use this method or something completely different?

Comment: Just define a view helper to calculate it, this is how to calculate http://stackoverflow.com/a/2311415/1789479, and here is how to define a view helper method http://www.rails-dev.com/custom-view-helpers-in-rails-4